# How to add extra attributes to UserProfile table in asp.net MVC 4

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection

I made a search for this for about 4 days and I couldn't find anything by any means that describe this step by step. I had found [this article](http://www.itorian.com/2012/11/adding-email-details-field-in.html) which describe how to add Email field to UserProfile table, the first step in this tutorial requires you to open DefaultConnection Database but I don't know how to do that.

So my question is:

1- how to add extra attributes in UserProfile database (using `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection` method).

2- What If I want to make my own database and let MVC to create `UserProfile` table with the extra attributes ?

If you have any questions let me know in the comments below.

EDIT:
I tried to add these extra attributes to `UserProfile` Class which I believe that it follows code first technique, after that I had changed the connection string to my own database then after building the project Tables (`UserProfile`, `webpages_Membership`, `webpages_OAuthMembership`, etc..) created successfully but with no extra attribute that I already added to UserProfile class before building.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework do that:

First you must enable migrations if you didn't did it.
After that look for 'ApplicatinUser' class and add property that you want(e.g FullName).